# ODBC Access Driver - no connection possible on VM with Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis, odbc, port, windows-server-2019

i have a problem with [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] used in ASP-Code on IIS on a VM with Windows Server 2019.
On my Testsystem not a VM it works but on VM it doesn't.

[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] x64 Version 2010 or 2016

Configured in ODBC x64 not in x32.

Error in Browser:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers Fehler "80004005'
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN has a mismatched driver and application architecture.

That make no sense for me, because I had configured it in x64 and it's a x64 ODBC driver.

If I used a x32 Driver, configured in x32, I get this error:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers Fehler "80004005'
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Disk or network error.

Could be a Portproblem?
Because: My IT, who administrates the VM, asked me which port the ODBC driver uses.
But does MS ODBC driver use ports at all?
Isn't that a database abstraction layer?

Does anyone know more about such a problem?

Thanks

Comment: I wrote it more than a decade ago, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lexli/database-for-web-applications Such miserable issues are expected when you use the bits in a scenario Access isn't designed for.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: It's used only in intranet. 
It's an old plattform yes but currently there is no other options for this company.